# Rotation affects scale transform anchor point

Tags: core-graphics, transformation

I have a CGPath which I'm trying to rotate, scale and translate. I also have a "resizable" UIView which acts as a helper for the user to allow him/her apply the transformation, so whenever this view's frame changes the new transformation is applied to the selected CGPath.
Also, I set the transform anchor point to the top-left corner. It scales and rotates just fine. However, if I set a rotation different than 0 and then scale, the anchor point is not at the top-left corner anymore. It seems like it is changed during the rotation, so let's say we start with 0 rotation and go all the way round to 360, then the anchor point is set back to the top-left corner as I would expect.

Here's the code I'm using to create the transform:

```
CGPoint anchorPointInPixels = CGPointMake(self.boundingBox.origin.x, self.boundingBox.origin.y);

CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, self.translation.x + anchorPointInPixels.x, self.translation.y + anchorPointInPixels.y);
t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, self.rotation);
t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, self.scale.x, self.scale.y);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, -anchorPointInPixels.x, -anchorPointInPixels.y);
self.transform = t;
```

Let me explain that piece of code a bit:
1. Path's points are in absolute coordinates
2. The bounding box is calculated just once and it is set as the rectangle enclosing all the points within the path. The bounding box is also in absolute coordinates
3. Translation specifies an offset from the bounding box's origin, so when the path has been created, translation equals to 0 and it remains like that until user moves it

So, how to make it rotate, without affecting the anchor point?

Thanks for reading!

Mariano

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this issue by concatenating the matrixes. Here's how the code looks like:

```
CGPoint anchorPointForScalingInPixels = CGPointMake(origin.x + size.width * self.anchorPointForScaling.x,
                                                    origin.y + size.height * self.anchorPointForScaling.y);

CGPoint anchorPointForRotationInPixels = CGPointMake(origin.x + size.width * self.anchorPointForRotation.x,
                                                     origin.y + size.height * self.anchorPointForRotation.y);

CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotation = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotation, anchorPointForRotationInPixels.x, anchorPointForRotationInPixels.y);
rotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotation, self.rotation);
rotation = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotation, -anchorPointForRotationInPixels.x, -anchorPointForRotationInPixels.y);

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
scale = CGAffineTransformTranslate(scale, anchorPointForScalingInPixels.x, anchorPointForScalingInPixels.y);
scale = CGAffineTransformScale(scale, self.scale.x, self.scale.y);
scale = CGAffineTransformTranslate(scale, -anchorPointForScalingInPixels.x, -anchorPointForScalingInPixels.y);

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.translation.x, self.translation.y);

CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate));
```

That way I can handle two anchor points, one for rotating and another one for scaling.